# ImageMagick tiling fails with JPEG

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, crop, tile

I'm trying to using ImageMagick's mogrify command to cut up a large image into 512x512 tiles, like so:

```
mogrify -path \temp2 -crop 512x512 \temp\IMG_4113.JPG
```

This creates the files IMG_4113-0.JPG, IMG_4113-1.JPG,... IMG_4113-53.JPG as I would expect. And each one is 512x512 (or smaller, if it's at the right or bottom edge) as I would expect. But each tile shows a copy of the ENTIRE original image. It is not slicing up the image into tiles like it should.

If I simply convert the JPEG to a PNG:

```
convert IMG_4113.JPG IMG_4113.PNG
```

and then run the same mogrify command on the PNG:

```
mogrify -path \temp2 -crop 512x512 \temp\IMG_4113.PNG
```

it works correctly: each tile is a small slice of the original, large image. Why doesn't this work with the JPEG, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Can you supply an example image and an example set of incorrect tiles so that we can see what you're referring to?  I haven't ever run into this problem.

Comment: I found out that the resulting tiles aren't ACTUALLY wrong. They just LOOK wrong in Windows Explorer's "Large Icons" view. If I open one of the images in a graphics program, or change the view a few times in Windows Explorer, then they look right. So I think this is mostly a Windows quirk. Comments and workarounds would still be welcome, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option `-strip` to your mogrify command line.

Comment: Thanks for the -strip suggestion, but it had no effect.